# Add additional parameters to event function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an event, and I want to add additional parameters to the named function. I tried following two things:

```
myDiv.addEventListener('click', evt.call(this, event, 'hello'));
```

And

```
myDiv.addEventListener('click', evt(event, 'hello'));
```

And the problem with both of them, is they get called right away, and don't get called when you click `myDiv`, i.e. when it's supposed to get called.

How can I add additional parameters to the named function event?

#### JSFiddle

```js
console.clear();

var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

function evt(event, param1) {
  console.log(event + ' and ' + param1)
}

myDiv.addEventListener('click', evt.call(this, event, 'hello'));
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)?

Comment: Read about `Function#bind`

Comment: @MikeC No, I'm not looking to change `this`. I just want to add more parameters to the event function

Comment: @Rayon I'm not looking to change this. I just want to add more parameters to the event function

Comment: @Jessica Right. Read more on `bind`. It lets you do just that. Like `call`, the first argument is the `this` value but the rest of them are the arguments you would be passing to the function.

Comment: Or just call this function inside `anonymous-function`

Comment: `function(event) {evt.call(this, event, 'hello');}`

Comment: @MikeC You're correct! I thought `bind` was to just add the `this`. Thanks! Which is better, performance wise, between using an anonymous  wrapper then `return evt.call(this, event, 'hello');`, or creating a variable with `bind`?

Comment: @Jessica You'd have to check to be sure but my assumption is that an anonymous function is faster since it doesn't have to bind `this`. It just depends on if you need `this` to be equal to something and if this is a performance critical section of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an anonymous wrapper:

```
myDiv.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    return evt.call(this, event, 'hello');
});
```

Alternately, you can give yourself a utility function (I tend to call it `curry`; purist may argue with that name). Here's an unoptimized off-the-cuff:

```
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "curry", {
    value: function() {
        var f = this;
        var boundArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return function() {
            return f.apply(this, boundArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };
    }
});
```

Then:

```
myDiv.addEventListener('click', evt.curry('hello'));
```

**But** you have to change the order of arguments in `evt` for that:

```
function evt(param1, event) {
  console.log(event + ' and ' + param1)
}
```

...since my version of `curry` passes it the curried arguments first, then the arguments that the curried version was called with. Although I suppose it's easy enough to swap them around if you prefer.

Here's that `curry` function in ES2015+:

```
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "curry", {
    value(...boundArgs) {
        var f = this;
        return function(...callArgs) {
            return f.call(this, ...boundArgs, ...callArgs);
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Which is better, performance wise, between using an anonymous  wrapper then `return evt.call(this, event, 'hello');`, or creating a variable with `bind`?

Comment: This is rather a meta comment, but: There's a ton of dups, but they are mostly hidden behind poor/irrelevant title and wording. Usually askers don't even know what is their actual problem. Jessica's post has a good title, maybe this post is a potential canonical dup target?

Comment: @Teemu: That's *exactly* what I found when I went looking, the actual problem hidden in `onxyz` attributes or jQuery or other really bad code. Jessica's is a nice, clear, simple one. I'm in, I'll save this link and use it for this in the future. I've made the answer a CW (just makes me feel better about pointing future ones at it).

Comment: @Jessica: It's really, really unlikely to matter which performs better. If I had to guess (and it would be a guess), I'd say probably the anonymous function. But there are lots of side-effects there, such as the fact that because it's a closure, it closes over everything that's in scope when you create it. Modern engines are very good at optimizing that these days, but still... That said, if you keep your functions small and avoid nesting deeply, I doubt it matters.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use an anonymous function for your event handler, that calls your `evt` function and passes in the event object and a parameter:

```
myDiv.addEventListener('click', function ( e ) {
  evt( e, 'hello' );
} );
```

Comment: Will `this-context` be persistent ?

Comment: Not with the above, no.

Comment: @Rayon No, but `this` isn't used in `evt`. If it were you could use `evt.call( this, e, 'hello' );`.